# Having a problem with the follower system, I am following myself in Django and also this error shows ValueError at /accounts/users/2/accept_follower/

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hey guys I am trying to send a follow request through the django notifications and the person at the other end will be either accepting or rejecting the request. But I have a problem that when the person at the other end accepts the request, this error is showing

```
ValueError at /accounts/users/2/accept_follower/
The view accounts.views.accept_follow_request didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

and he is following himself. I tried printing out the current_user and user in send_follow_request function and it is showing the 2 users correctly, but in the accept_follow_request function, both the users are same! How to change that?

This is the code I have now.

```
def send_follow_request(request, id):
    current_user = request.user
    user = Account.objects.get(id=id)
    notify.send(request.user, recipient=user, verb='has sent you a follow request', target=user)
    return redirect('posts:userprofile', user.username)

def accept_follow_request(request, id):
    current_user = request.user
    user = Account.objects.get(id=id)
    contact, created = Contact.objects.get_or_create(user_from=request.user, user_to=user, follow_status='AC')
    if user != request.user:
        create_action(request.user, 'started following', user)
        notify.send(request.user, recipient=user, verb='started following you')
        return redirect('all_user_notifications')
```

This is the notification view

```
class AllNotificationsList(LoginRequiredMixin, NotificationViewList):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if get_config()['SOFT_DELETE']:
            qset = self.request.user.notifications.active()
        else:
            qset = self.request.user.notifications.all()
        return qset
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

This is the form I have in the notificaion template:

```
                {% if notice.target == user %}
                <form action="{% url 'accept_follow_request' user.id %}">
                    <button class="btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">Accept</button>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancel</a>
                </form>
```

This is the model I have

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='rel_from_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='rel_to_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    follow_status = models.CharField(choices=FOLLOW_STATUS, max_length=10)


    #USER_FROM IS THE ONE WHO IS FOLLOWING AND USER_TO IS ONE BEING FOLLOWED
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user_from} follows {self.user_to}'


following = models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Contact, related_name='followers', symmetrical=False)

    #adding the above field to User Model class
user_model = get_user_model()
user_model.add_to_class('following', models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Contact, related_name='followers',
                                symmetrical=False))
```

url:

```
path('<int:id>/accept_follower/', views.accept_follow_request, name='accept_follow_request'),
```

Traceback:

```
    C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
exc 
ValueError("The view accounts.views.accept_follow_request didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.")
get_response    
<bound method BaseHandler._get_response of <django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x039FC6E8>>
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/users/2/accept_follower/'>
C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
            raise ValueError( …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
callback    
<function accept_follow_request at 0x04D19E80>
callback_args   
()
callback_kwargs 
{'id': 2}
middleware_method   
<bound method CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view of <django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware object at 0x03A2B3D0>>
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/users/2/accept_follower/'>
resolver    
<URLResolver 'socialwebsite.urls' (None:None) '^/'>
resolver_match  
ResolverMatch(func=accounts.views.accept_follow_request, args=(), kwargs={'id': 2}, url_name=accept_follow_request, app_names=[], namespaces=[], route=accounts/users/<int:id>/accept_follower/)
response    
None
self    
<django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x039FC6E8>
view_name   
'accept_follow_request'
wrapped_callback    
<function accept_follow_request at 0x04D19E80>
```

Thanks!

Comment: so turn on debugging or pull up logs and post trackback, and add bit more details regarding your models for instance

Comment: It isn't showing any error instead the person just follows himself and the output im getting is the HttpResponse. I have updated the question with the models

Comment: It is error 500 default message when debug is turned off, so as I said before you need to learn to debug ( good step in that direction would be to learn to get error trackback )

Comment: My debug is on, so how do I get the traceback? I used a form with accept_follow_request as action.

Comment: Hello
I have added the traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem that user == request.user as in that case you are not returning any response ( you have if but not else)

I would guess that constructed URL for accept_follower has wrong id in URL ( notified user instead of id of user that requested follow)

This would be reason you are following yourself

```
contact, created = Contact.objects.get_or_create(user_from=request.user, user_to=user, follow_status='AC')
```

so something in a line of following ( instead user.id (its the target) send id of sender ):

```
   {% if notice.target == user %}
    <form action="{% url 'accept_follow_request' notice.actor.id %}">
        <button class="btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">Accept</button>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancel</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: I have added the url pattern and the template in the question. can you please have a look at it?

Comment: So, isn't this the proper way to do it?

Comment: I tried that now. but getting no reverse match error. 
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/user/all_user_notifications/
Reverse for 'accept_follow_request' with arguments '(<Account: Test User>,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/accept_follower/$']

Comment: .id was obviously missing,
you should add also check if notification exists otherwise one person could follow even people he did not got request to follow by forging request

Comment: It worked in the reverse way like when I accept the request, the person accepted is following the user which has send the request.
So i reversed the users in the Contact model and it worked perfect.

Thanks a lot!